# Calculating percent for 1,000s of objects slow in xcode

Tags: ios, core-data

can anyone suggest a faster approach to the following:

I have an array of 5,000 managed objects (faulted) (an array of car.h objects)

Each object has a set of items (toCarParts.h). This set can have any number of objects.

Now i want to sort these out by the most matches in my search query carpart array.

I search for wheel, seat, window, mirror.

The method will go through each car and find the closest match, and calculate a percentage.  So if car a has wheel, seat, window, mirror, mat, tire, wiper, pipe --> the % should be 50%.  (Matched 4/8 parts.

This is simple enough, but the problem is with 5,000 items the search takes a long time (even using coredata).

The logic i am using goes something like: (Pseudocode)

```
 For each Car*car in array.
   NSMutableArray *x=[car tocarparts]allobjects];
   For the count of objects in x.
     Carpart*part=objectatindex...i.
     If the name of this matches one of my parts 
       add a count to my counter.
   At the end of the loop counter/[x count] =%.car.percent=%.
```

There has to be a better way, any suggestions? (I think its the dividing and checking each part that takes forever.

Thank you in advance.

Edited, added code below:.

-(NSMutableArray*)calculatePercentagePerFind:(NSMutableArray*)CarArray:(NSMutableArray*)partsArray{
    NSArray*defaultParts =[NSArray arrayWithArray:[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getObjectUserDefault:@"AvailableDefaultParts"]];

```
int lowestPercentMatchInt=[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getIntegerUserDefault:@"lowestPercentageMatch"];

NSMutableArray*partsFromCarArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray*returnArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray *partsWithDefaultParts =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:partsArray];
[partsWithDefaultParts addObjectsFromArray:defaultParts];


for (int i=0; i<[CarArray count]; i++) {
    double matchCount=0;
    Car *CarResult =(Car*)[CarArray objectAtIndex:i];

            //Check if it will at least be 30% match
    double number1 = [partsWithDefaultParts count];
        number1 =(number1/[CarResult.numberOfParts doubleValue])*100;
        if (number1>lowestPercentMatchInt) {
            partsFromCarArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[CarResult toParts]allObjects]];
            NSMutableArray *faultedParts=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (int i =0; i<[partsFromCarArray count]; i++) {
                CarPart*part = (CarPart*)[partsFromCarArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    [faultedParts addObject:part.name];
            }
        // for each part in the Car
        for (NSString *partInCar in partsWithDefaultParts){
            //if the search parts contain that part, add one to count
            if ([faultedParts containsObject:partInCar]) {
                matchCount++;
            }
        }
        //Calculate percent match
        double percentMatch = matchCount;

        percentMatch =(percentMatch/[CarResult.numberOfParts doubleValue])*100;

        //if at least 30%(user default) then add the percent match to Car result
        if (percentMatch >lowestPercentMatchInt) {
            if (percentMatch>100) {
                CarResult.percentMatch = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:100.00];
            }else{
                CarResult.percentMatch = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:percentMatch];
            }
            [returnArray addObject:CarResult];
        }
}
}
NSLog(@"Percent Matched Cars = %i",[returnArray count]);
return [self arrangeByHighestPercentMatch:returnArray];
```

}

Comment: This sounds like a perfect question for (http://codereview.stackexchange.com) Maybe you would consider posting it there, but you would need to provide the code in order to get help (which you should do here as well, btw)

Comment: Will do, thank you for the page

Comment: Are you looking for one percentage for each car (to be displayed, e.g., in a table view), or for an overall percentage of "usage", within a pool of 5000 cars, of an arbitrarily chosen set of parts?

Comment: One percentage per car (in tableview)

Comment: it is very slow indeed, can you show us the data structure instead of the rating code? because the data structure could give more information for what type of searching algorithm can be better choice...

Comment: Added the full code.  Also i am trying to display this in order (highest match at the top)

Comment: Also data structure here is: Car.h (name, make, etc). ToCarPart relationship. Each carPart.h has (name, maker, model). I am only matching part name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which I believe will minimize the strain on core data.

```
NSSet *selectionSet; // contains the selected parts
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"self IN %@", selectionSet];
float percentageSum = 0;
NSSet *parts;
for (Car *car in fetchedObjects) {
   parts = car.parts;  // so the relationship is retrieved only once
   percentageSum += 
       [parts filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate].count*1.0f 
                                          / (parts.count*1.0f);
}
return percentageSum/fetchedObjects.count;
```

This would average out the percentages across all cars. There are other methods to weigh the parts differently in the aggregate.

It is not clear from your question, but if you do not need a total percentage but one percentage for each car there would be no need to loop through all cars - you could just calculate the percentage on the fly when displaying it (e.g. with a transient property).

Comment: hi, this line [parts filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate].count / parts.count; gives me 0 (even though I know there is a match), any thoughts why?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make them floats. Integer division will give 0. See above for correction.

Comment: Just saw your answer to my comment above. Well, the formula you need is in the loop, but you do not need to loop.

Comment: perfect, the logic is awesome. The only change I made was to use a compound or predicate using the array of car parts (for some reason self IN) didn't do it.  THank you so much, I think this should be faster. Also, does NSLog slow down the processor at all?

Comment: NSLog slows it down a lot. You can check with time stamps. Please tell me your working predicate so I can update the answer. I had to infer things about your data model by guessing...

Comment: NSMutableArray*predicateArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<[allParts count]; i++) {
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==[c] %@",[allParts objectAtIndex:i]];
        [predicateArray addObject:predicate];
    }
    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];

Comment: Ah, OK -you had an array of names, not of objects. That is even slower than doing it with the actual objects I think.

Comment: so should I pull up those objects you think?

Comment: so pull up carpart objects and then I imagine your SELF IN predicate would work?

Comment: Exactly right. Get an array of the car part objects and compare against them with my predicate.